# Modifying a ggplot of odds ratios

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a plot of 21 different odds ratios and their respective confidence intervals - the odds ratios are stratified by racial group (7 groups) and death category (3 categories), and I'm pretty close to what I want, I just am stuck on a few things.

Here is what I've run so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("ggstance")

early <- data.frame(labels=c("Early:Overall","Early:Non-Hispanic White","Early:Non-Hispanic Black","Early:Non-Hispanic Asian",
         "Early:Non-Hispanic Other","Early:Hispanic","Early:Unknown","Neo:Overall","Neo:NHW","Neo:NHB",
         "Neo:NHA","Neo:NHO","Neo:Hisp","Neo:Unknown","Inf:Overall","Inf:NHW","Inf:NHB","Inf:NHA","Inf:NHO",
         "Inf:Hisp","Inf:Unknown"),
                    odds=c(317.77,355.54,187.82,495.49,213.23,345.45,1818.05,114.02,128.84,52.70,271.15,57.86,158.21,579.40,46.76,52.50,22.46,104.81,22.41,67.93,214.85),
                    low=c(282.25,301.37,141.12,292.51,113.06,263.85,624.20,103.53,112.63,42.20,168.26,34.34,126.00,255.58,42.87,46.46,18.42,67.25,14.29,55.32,108.01),
                    high=c(357.64,419.32,249.42,831.05,396.78,450.64,6710.68,125.41,147.03,65.47,426.48,93.53,197.31,1354.38,50.93,59.16,27.16,157.91,33.76,82.78,416.06),
group=rep(c("Overall","Non-Hispanic White","Non-Hispanic Black","Non-Hispanic Asian",
                  "Non-Hispanic Other","Hispanic","Unknown"),3),
                    death=c("Early:Overall"="Early Neonatal Death","Early:Non-Hispanic White"="Early Neonatal Death",
                            "Early:Non-Hispanic Black"="Early Neonatal Death","Early:Non-Hispanic Asian"="Early Neonatal Death",
                            "Early:Non-Hispanic Other"="Early Neonatal Death","Early:Hispanic"="Early Neonatal Death",
                            "Early:Unknown"="Early Neonatal Death","Neo:Overall"="Neonatal Death","Neo:NHW"="Neonatal Death",
                            "Neo:NHB"="Neonatal Death","Neo:NHA"="Neonatal Death","Neo:NHO"="Neonatal Death","Neo:Hisp"="Neonatal Death",
                            "Neo:Unknown"="Neonatal Death","Inf:Overall"="Infant Death","Inf:NHW"="Infant Death",
                            "Inf:NHB"="Infant Death","Inf:NHA"="Infant Death","Inf:NHO"="Infant Death","Inf:Hisp"="Infant Death","Inf:Unknown"="Infant Death"))

ggplot(early,aes(x = odds, y = group)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.001, xmax = 1000,
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = low, xmax = high)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = group,shape=death), size = 3 ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(20, 600)) +
  facet_grid(labels~., switch = "y") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "points"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color="white"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        legend.box.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))
plot+ labs(title="Race-Stratified Odds Ratios by Death Category",x="Odds Ratios",y="Maternal Race Group")
```

And this is the plot I currently have:
[image]

I'm not sure why the background of the plot is still gray or why some of the shapes are partially obstructed, but I'm assuming there's some kind of grey bars over the background. I've tried deleting each line of my code one by one and the grey never went away. I'm trying to make the background just white, so if anyone has any suggestions for how to do that I would really appreciate it!

Also, I was hoping to not show the individual labels (i.e. "Early:Non-Hispanic White") on the plot and instead only have the 3 death labels (i.e. "Early Neonatal Death"). Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are *drawing* the gray background with your call to `geom_rect`, which by default is gray. You can either make this white, or better still, remove it and use scales and themes to give your plot the desired look.

To remove the color guide from the legend, you can add `+ scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_none())` to your plot.

The symbols are being clipped (and don't align perfectly with the labels) because each of the facets is actually preserving a tiny space for *all* the groups. You therefore need to specify `scales = "free_y"` to level everything out, give your error bars greater width and prevent the symbols from clipping.

You can also choose a global theme that requires less individual tweaks to the `theme` parameters, and you may prefer the look of making the strip labels right-aligned and external to the y axis line.

```r
ggplot(early,aes(x = odds, y = group)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = low, xmax = high)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = group, shape = death), size = 3) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_none()) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(20, 600)) +
  facet_grid(labels ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") +
  labs(title = "Race-Stratified Odds Ratios by Death Category",
       x     = "Odds Ratios", 
       y     = "Maternal Race Group") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing.y     = unit(0, "points"),
        axis.text.y         = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.placement     = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left   = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1),
        strip.background.y  = element_blank(),
        legend.box.margin   = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))
```

[image]